# How can I add a cube?

Tags: python, modeling, objects, workflow

I am trying to add cubes to my scene. I'm sure there are lots of ways to get a cube into the scene (but for the purposes of this question, *I have no idea what they are*) - Are there any ways to add a cube that are easier than using the python console and manually adding them by using this command?

```
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

```
import bpy
from random import randint
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()

#how many cubes you want to add
count = 10

for c in range(0,count):
    x = randint(-10,10)
    y = randint(-10,10)
    z = randint(-10,10)
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(x,y,z))
```

Run this script in the *Text Editor* with the *Run Script* button.
The var *count* controls how many cubs will be added.
The three vars x, y, and z are random numbers for the placement of the cubes. Change the sets of numbers, to change the range where the cubes can be added on each axes.

Answer (score 13):

If you need a more specific shape for you distributed cubes, you can use a particle system.

1. Make a cage that will contain all the cubes.
2. Add a particle system set it to *Hair* then set to *Advanced*, and set the *Emit From* to *Volume*.
3. Set the *Dupli Object* under the *Render* section to the cube that you want to distribute.

[image: particle system settings]

Answer (score 11):

My personal favorite is the array modifier. Simply add the modifier to any cube and set the amount you want and *BAM!*

[image]

Multiple arrays in union can be used to quickly create thousands of cubes.

[image]

Comment: Loved that way.

Answer (score 10):

Another option would be to duplicate the cubes by a particle system, you didn't mention how the cubes should be arranged.

Cubes on cubes:

[image]

Or some other shape:

[image]

Comment: That's quite interesting. U can convert cubes to externally solid cube but with internal plastic volume splitted in cubes. So you create something like a 3d grid inside with is a cube with half a plastic ( and hours of work ) for an 3d printer. Im rlly new to Blender but that did came to my mind today. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 8):

you can also get more cubes in your scene by selecting the default cube (if you already edited and/or deleted the default cube then you must add another cube), and pressing  <kbd>Shift</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  to duplicate it. Or you can select  <kbd>Alt</kbd>  <kbd>D</kbd>  to make another instance of the default cube that will remain editable.

All of the default objects can be found here, In nice color and with good lighting. All of which is packed into a nice scene with *GLSL* shading.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can use <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>>*mesh*>*cube*.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

You can also do this by saving a scene with the default objects such as this one.

[image]

click File>Append>

[image]

select the file that has the cube you need.

[image]

select the folder for objects

[image]

select the cube you want to copy. in this case it is called "cube"

[image]

this will add append the cube form your other file.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the add menu at the bottom right coner of the 3d view:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use the create tab in the tools panel:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

There is a fast, easy ten key combination shortcut for this.

<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd><kbd>D</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd><kbd>U</kbd><kbd>B</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

This method may seem a bit tiring if you only want to add one cube, but the next cube can be added much easier. Also, if you can type *Really* fast it might be faster than some of the other solutions to this question.

[image]

If you are really lazy, or simply want to keep a few keys working on your keyboard, you can skip typing the <kbd>B</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> at the end because add cube will be the only one left in the search menu.

For the next cube you add, you will only need to press <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>
(assuming that you have not typed anything else in the search menu)

Technically this method places less wear on your keyboard, because <kbd>Space</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> requires fewer key presses than <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> <kbd>C</kbd>

Comment: I think space + "cub" is enough - 4 key presses!

Answer (score 6):

You can also model a cube by adding a plane
[image: Add Plane]

Then select the plane and press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter edit mode.

[image]

then press <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>2</kbd> to extrude 2 units. If you are using default units, this will make a default sized cube.

[image]

To place the origin in the center, exit edit mode by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> again. then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> and select *Origin to Center of Mass* this will place the origin in the center of the cube.

[image]

Now all you need to do is add your favorite color to it, and you will have a perfect cube.

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly. Why the -1?

Answer (score 1):

Add a plane to your default cube (yes, keep it!)

Add geometry nodes modifier to plane.

Use this node setup:

[image]

and you get:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press `F3` key, then type `add cube` into the search box and choose first item:
[image]