# How to make half of a square circular

Tags: modeling

I have a square. I want half of it to be circular, like this
[image: sketch of shape]
(image is from a topdown view)

I kept loop cutting but I couldn't find a way to make it truly "round" and do it evenly.

NOTE: to be very specific, it should only be round horizontally, the rest should be untouched. Like this:

[image: 3D sketch of shape]
(please excuse my horrifying drawing)

Answer (score 9):

1. Add a Cylinder <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Mesh* > *Cylinder*, set the *Cap Fill Type* to *Nothing*.
2. Select half of it and delete with <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd> [image: modeling cylinder]
3. Select the four vertices along the edge
4. Extrude to make the long sides
   [image: extrude]
5. Fill the back, top and bottom to get this.
   [image: final result]

Note the top and bottom are [Ngons](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/1684/2217), witch in many cases are undesirable. To get a quads all over the top use [grid fill](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/14580/2217).

Answer (score 9):

With this technique you can add half-circles anywhere on your **existing** geometry:

1. Add a Cube and scale it 1.5 in X axis - <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>+<kbd>1.5</kbd>:

   [image]

   Be sure not to scale it in objectmode. If you do apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.
2. Select 2 front edges and Bevel them - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. Adjust *Segments* with mousewheel and type <kbd>1</kbd> for the *Offset* - it will create a perfect half-circle:

   [image]
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> > *Remove Doubles*. Enjoy:)

Answer (score 6):

You can moddel this shape from a cube.

First add a cube, If you are unsure how do do that, see this question,
[How to add a cube](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21589/5426).

[image: Cube]

It does not need to be blue, however it looks cool blue.

Once you have a cube select one of the faces, and set the 3D cursor to that face. If you are unsure how to move the 3D Cursor, see this question [How to move the 3D coursor](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/13828/5426)

[image]

Once you have a face selected and the 3D cursor set to that face, select Only one edge on that face. it is very important that you **Do not** move the 3D cursor in this step.

[image]

Once you have an edge selected press NumPad <kbd>7</kbd> This will move your viewpoint to the top view. it is also **Very important** now that you **DO NOT** move the 3D cursor. It must be in the same location as before.

[image]

Once you are in the top view with the 3D cursor in place and the correct edge selected, press <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>R</kbd> Then adjust the settings for the spin tool to 180° and a reasonable number of steps.

[image]

There is one thing you can skip here but it is better if you do this step. When you spun the edge around 180°, it created an edge where there already was an edge. First, rotate the view to a better position. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select the entire object.

[image]

Now click on Remove doubles.

[image]

Now that the required mesh has been generated, and there are no duplicate vertices, your object is nearly done. First Rotate the view so you can see this face. Select it and press <kbd>delete</kbd>.

[image]

A menu will open with delete options. select *Face*.

[image]

Now that the internal face is gone, we must complete the object.

Select these edges.

[image]

Press <kbd>F</kbd>. This will fill the empty space with a face.

[image]

Once the other side is filled, The object will be complete.

Select the edges on the bottom - Same as the top

[image]

Then press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill this side.

[image]

Now your object is complete. Exit edit mode by pressing <kbd>tab</kbd>

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try adding a circle to the scene and making half of it like a square instead of the other way around.

[image: Circle]
[image: half Circle]
[image: Extruding]

Hope this helps!

Comment: Copying other users answers is not recommended.

Comment: I was second if not first to answer this question and at the time I started there were no previous answers. So sue me.

Comment: Yes you were second. But apparently David had started writing his answer before you.

Comment: @Dr.Who This answer was not first, don't worry though, nobody will sue you. **X-27** David also posted his answer first

Comment: @X-27 Let's try to give users the benefit of the doubt that they simply didn't see the other answers, I know it's happened to me.

Comment: well  might sue him... C'mon guys lighten up, it's a game.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would do it,

- Create a plane
- select one edge of the plane, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> > cursor to selected
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to add a circle
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> > Remove doubles
- Delete the part of the arc that resides within the squarea (That's a word now) of the plane
- select it all (<kbd>A</kbd>) and hit <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude to desired height.
- **BOOM!** victory.