# How can I create an L shape with two beveled sides?

Tags: modeling

I've been trying to get this right but it seems like I get stuck every time.

This is what I'm looking for, but time and time again I've been stumped.

[image]

I have to add this boolean difference to it when it's sculpted out:

[image]

But when I go to sub surf it, this happens and it becomes very difficult to add loop cuts around them to fix it, actually they don't even show up at all and using the knife tool is too difficult.

[image]

Here's a cruder but see through version of the shape I'm looking for.

[image]

Comment: so where exactly are you having the problem. the not-yet-freshman got it in 3 minutes? I don't see a problem.

Comment: The part where I have to translate the drawing into a 3D model on blender!

Comment: But... But...you just *do* it. make the profile and extrude it where it needs to go.

Comment: See [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/26974/how-to-make-half-of-a-square-circular) question. then modify it to meet your needs.

Comment: Lmfaoooo that helps a little, cheers xD

Comment: Very nice hand drawings, by the way!

Comment: SubSurf doesn't like NGons, you can try to bevel sharp edges but i suggest a clean quad topology if you really need subsurf.

Comment: Don't understand the boolean operation in the second picture, because it's not shown in the sketches. Could you elaborate? Why the answers doesn't solve your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with the bevel tool.

Start with a cube, in edit mode (<kbd>TAB</kbd>) select the edges you want to make round:

[image]

press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to use the bevel tool and set the parameters for **Amount** to **1** and **Profile** to **0.5**

[image]

Remove doubles (press the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>v</kbd>->Remouve Doubles)

[image]
To make the first shape you describe extrude these faces:

[image]

For the second shape you'd need to make a cut before extruding:

[image]

Comment: to soften the edges see: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/23597/1853

Comment: i would actually turn on snapping, it looks like he needs *a lot* of accuracy in here.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend the following workflow.

- Start with a UV sphere.
- Delete all but two octants (leave the top right, front and back).
  To do this, select the equatorial and meridian edge rings (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>[image: Right mouse button] RMB</kbd>) and use the *Rip* tool (<kbd>V</kbd>), then mouse over each octant and use *Select Linked* (<kbd>L</kbd>).
- Extrude (<kbd>E</kbd>) the bottom ring down to create a long half-capsule ring (upside-down "U").
- Extrude the long ring out a bit, then create a face at the boundary with the sphere.
- Extrude the top part of what used to be the long ring out a bit more.
- Fill remaining holes with faces.
- Bevel interior edges, if desired.

Here's a demo (warning: large gif may be slow to load; consider viewing [this gfycat video](http://www.gfycat.com/SnappyPeriodicEquestrian) instead).

[image: Slow-loading gif; see gfycat link instead]

You mentioned that you wanted to add subsurf.
I would recommend against that, in this case.
Instead, just use a sufficiently high-resolution UV sphere that everything is smooth already, and add a slight bevel to the edges.
(I didn't really do this in my demonstration; you could be more careful.)
See [iKlsR's answer to "How can I make sharp geometric 3D models look more realistic?"](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/248/372) for more information.