# How can I add an object to a scene?

Tags: objects, scene

I'm a beginner. I just want to add a generic sphere/cube or something to my scene but I can't find the exact menu for this? Literally googled "how to add an object to a scene in Blender" and couldn't find anything.

Comment: First of all - be nice. Secondly, literally I have copied and paste "how to add an object to a scene in Blender" in Google and this is third link: http://www.dummies.com/web-design-development/adding-objects-to-a-scene-in-blender/

Comment: Even a beginner can still be nice. Lets try this. Welcome to the site. Please try to just ask your question without calling your self stupid, or blender a beginner.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> *Mesh* > *UV Sphere*
- 3D View header *Add* > *Mesh* > *UV Sphere*
- Toolshelf in the 3D View *Create* tab then the *UV Sphere* button.

[image: animated gif showing how to add an object]

And those are just the normal simple ways to add a sphere.

[This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/21589/2217) probably could be of some help, at least you'll have a cube...

Comment: YES. And the answers to that linked questions absolutely *only work on cubes* lol :)